# How to add custom option to target in makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am working at a make file with a target that allows me to run System Component Tests(SCTs). The target is called sct which after some pre-work calls the command `python -m pytest -n auto`. I need to add a optional flag to the target to switch between the mentioned command line and `python -m pytest -n0`.

If nothing is set (`make sct`) pytest should be started with the option `-n auto`. If the flag is added (name should be "non-dist" -> sth. like `make sct --non-dist`) pytest should be started with the `-n0` option.

Is there a way to add an flag to my sct target? If you don't have a solution some keywords to find a solution myself would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common arrangement is to define a variable, which can easily be overridden on the command line.

```
# default flags
SCTFLAGS := -n auto
sct:
    python -m pytest $(SCTFLAGS)
```

You can add some embellishments to make it easier for the person running `make` to pick a valid value, but this should at least get you started.  Just `make` will run with the default value, and

```
make SCTFLAGS=-n0
```

will run with the non-prod flags.